# Checking strings with

Tags: python

I have a series of if statements in a function like this:

```
if time == "%%00":
    #code
elif time == "%%15":
    #code
elif time == "%%30":
    #code
elif time == "%%45":
    #code
```

Where time is 24 hour format ie. 0000-2400 and I'm checking what 15 interval time is at. All the statements are ignored however, so "%%interval" doesn't work. Is it just something simple I'm missing here or do I need a different method?

Comment: See the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.

Comment: What in the world would make you think `%` is some kind of crazy string wildcard in Python (or that equality tests accept wildcards to begin with)?

Comment: I've been doing my first semester of sql at the same time and it uses % in statements such as WHERE str LIKE "%asd%". I thought it'd work similarly in python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

```
if time.endswith("00"):
    #code
elif time[-2:] == "15":
    #code
elif re.match(".{2}30", time):
    #code
elif time.endswith("45"):
    #code
```

Answer (score 0):

fundamentally you are comparing string literals and nothing more, theres a couple ways of doing this, heres one without regular expressions.

```
if   time[-2:] == "00":
    #code
elif time[-2:] == "15":
    #code
elif time[-2:] == "30":
    #code
elif time[-2:] == "45":
    #code
```

`[-2:]` will grab the last two chars from the string

heres one with regular expression, Im not a big fan of them, they can generate subtle bugs, but thats just my opinion.

```
if re.match('..00', time):
    #code
elif re.match('..15', time):
    # code
elif re.match('..30', time):
    # code
elif re.match('..45', time):
    # code
```

the `.` simply means match any char, except for `\n`, `re.match` either returns an object or `None` if there was no match.